# Unity3D c# 2D Game Camera Follow is making jumps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I made an 2D endless runner game using Unity, where the Player Object moves upwards, but for the Viewer he remains on the same spot because the Camera is following him. The Following works pretty well, but the problem is that it is making small jumps every few seconds. The jumps are small and thus are not affecting the gameplay in general but they are big enough to make it seem like the game is not running smoothly.

I can't even tell whether it is the Camera that is making the jumps or the Player Object. But I think it is the Camera, because the spawning obstacles are also making jumps. What may be the issue? Am I using the right method for the Camera?

```
public class Player
{
    float speed = 5f;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(0, speed*Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

And this is the Script which is attached to the Camera:

```
public class CameraFollow
{
    private Vector3 FollowVector;
    public Transform Player;
    void LadeUpdate()
    {
        FollowVector = Player.position - new Vector3(0, -4f, 10);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, FollowVector, Time.deltaTime * 4f);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the jump happen every 4 seconds? I think the problem might be in your `Vector3.Lerp` function. It's basically a loose camera-follow, that takes 4 seconds (`Time.deltaTime * 4f`) to smoothly go from Point A to point B. Every 4 seconds it resets its path, hence the hop. At least that's my theory.

If you don't mind the camera rigidly following the player, I would just remove the Lerp and just set the `transform.position` to be the FollowVector value like so:

```
void LadeUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Player.position - new Vector3(0, -4f, 10);
    }
```

Comment: This solution makes the camera follow really smoothly, however I need some sort of Lerp, because the Player can sometimes speed up for 1 second, that makes him go a little higher, but then brings him back to the prior camera position.
Is it possible to use a Lerp Function in your Solution?

Comment: Only thing I can imagine at the moment is you Lerp only when the player speeds up. Maybe an IF statement that activates the Lerp for 1 second when the speed-up is triggered, otherwise default to the approach above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Vector3.MoveTowards

```
float step =  speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.position - new Vector3(0, -4f, 10f), step);
```